# Django with Heroku, No module named django core management

Tags: django, heroku

I have my Django app pushed to heroku successfully, however when I try to open a shell such as `heroku run python manage.py shell` I get `django-no-module-named-django-core-management` error. My app also does not render properly when I visit the URL. I've checked all the settings and can't figure out I'm getting this error. My requirements.txt file is setup correctly with all the dependencies (including Django) from my virtual env.

Comment: I never setup a .gitignore file, could that be the problem with my virtualENV files?

Comment: How do you know Django is installed?

Comment: @rnevius I ran `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and Django==1.7.1 was listed there.  Is that version too new for heroku?

Comment: my `env/` folder sits outside of my django project, is that a problem?

Comment: @ChetSteadman that's not the problem. Give me little brief to help solving your problem.! Did you run `foreman start` locally then it's access able? show me heroku logs otherwise just tell what error code you are getting there.. ! No module named django core management leading lot of way to analyze .. then analyze

Answer (score 2):

you need to activate your virtualenv

```
. bin/activate
```

only then your code has access to all modules inside virtualenv

Comment: Do I put that line in the Procfile?

Comment: I already activated my virtualENV  locally prior to doing anything

Comment: pipenv shell, then your command. @RustyShackleford, have you really? Thanks doniyor!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could check your requirements.txt file
`psycopg2==2.5.3`